# PHP: How to strip all types of extensions from URL (incl. period)

Tags: php, url, strip

I am new to PHP and hope someone can help me with this.

I want PHP to give me the name of the **current page of my website**. 
The important thing is that I need this without any leading slashes and without any trailing extensions etc., just the plain page name.

**Example:**
The URL of a page is http://www.myurl.com/index.php?lang=en
In this case it should only return "index".

I found a way to get rid of the leading part using the following but have trouble to remove the trailing part since this is variable (it can be just `.php` or `.php?lang=en` or `.php=lang=de` etc.).

```
$pageName = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

The only thing I found is the following but this doesn't cover the variable extension part:

```
$pageName = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ".php");
```

**Can someone tell me how to get rid of the trailing part as well ?**

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: If I recall correctly, it is somewhere in the htaccess configuration.

Comment: Thanks - I don't think this is the right approach here. I just need this for a variable within the page not for the actual URL itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`parse_url`](https://php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php) in combination with [`pathinfo`](https://php.net/manual/function.pathinfo.php):

```
<?php
$input  = 'http://www.myurl.com/index.php?lang=en';
$output = pathinfo(parse_url($input, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_FILENAME); 

var_dump($output); // => index
```

demo: https://eval.in/382330

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is:

```
$url = "http://www.myurl.com/index.php?lang=en";

preg_match('/\/([\w-_]+)\.php/i',$url,$match);
echo $match[1];
```

If you need help with the regex look here:
https://regex101.com/r/cM8sS3/1

Answer (score 2):

here is simplest solution.

```html
$pagename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$a = explode(".",$pagename);
echo $a[0];
```

Comment: This will have issues if the `$pagename` has periods beyond the extension, e.g. `foo.bar.php`.

Comment: Thanks - this is great too but I need to cover possible other periods as well (as Grokify mentioned).

Comment: user following code
$pagename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$part   = implode('.', explode('.', $pagename, -1));

Answer (score 0):

[A tutorial on how to do it](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

> With an .htaccess file you can:
>
> Redirect the user to different page
>
> Password protect a specific directory
>
> Block users by IP Preventing hot
>
> linking of your images
>
> Rewrite URIs
>
> Specify your own Error Documents

Comment: Thanks - I don't think this is the right approach here. I just need this for a variable within the page not for the actual URL itself.

Comment: I guess you need to reword your question. because your question is asking for removal of extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//return url
$pageName = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]);

function Url($pageName) {
    $pageName= strtolower($pageName);
    $pageName= str_replace('.',' ',$pageName);
    $pageName= preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $pageName);
    $pageName= preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $pageName);
    $pageName= preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $pageName);
    return $pageName ;
}
$cleanurl=Url($pageName);
echo $cleanurl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where I would just use a regular expression. Here's the code:

```
$pagename = basename("http://www.myurl.com/index.php?lang=en");

$pagename = preg_replace("/\..*/", "", $pagename);
```

You can see a working demo here: https://ideone.com/RdrHzc

The first argument is an expression that matches for a literal period followed by any number of characters. The second argument tells the function to replace the matched string with an empty string, and the last argument is the variable to operate on.